# How would I get the best quality plot into a TeX editor which includes the legends?

Tags: plotting, export, latex

I have currently used "Save Selection As" after highlighting the graph and legend and then saved it as a PNG file, but the quality isn't brilliant. I am using TeXworks on Windows 7. The "Copy As LaTeX" gives an error message as well, guess it doesn't like the legends.

Saving it as a PDF or EPS file messes up the title in the plot, which are some recommendations I saw on different questions.

Comment: make sure the notebook window magnification is set to 100%. Otherwise the png quality will be bad. This is a known issue.

Comment: @Nasser Does this work both ways, i.e. will a magnification greater than 100% also result in bad png quality?

Comment: @MarkusRoellig if you try to save a plot as png, when the notebook is set at magnification not 100%, you'll notice the png image quality is not good when viewed using external image viewer. Try again, but with 100%, you'll see it is better quality. It has to be 100%. At least that was the case when I last tried it. windows 7, v 9.01

Answer (score 3):

I made the graph smaller (which turned out to be the reason why it was displaying weirdly in PDF/EPS), then highlighted both the graph and legend, saved selection as an EPS file and it has worked very nicely!